# multiple files to one folder shells script

Tags: shell, file-io

I am trying to write a script that will move files into folders which are created based on the file names
There are 2 copys of each file with the exact same name but different file extensions.

example

**Before**

```
dir1 - one.txt one.rtf two.txt two.rtf other.txt other.rtf
```

**After**

```
dir1 - one two other

dir1/one - one.txt one.rtf

dir1/two - two.txt two.rtf

dir1/other - other.txt other.rtf
```

I previously put together a file to folder script but im not sure how to get it to put multiple files into 1 folder

heres the file to folder code.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="/home/user1/Desktop/f2f/"

for file in ${dir}/*
do
        mkdir -p "${file/./#}"
        mv "${file}" "${file/./#}/"
done
```

anyways any help would be appreciated, naming conventions and files extensions will always be the same if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very sure what the purpose of your original script is, as you seem to generate a folders for every `<file>.<extension>` named `<filename>#<extension>` where you then place `<file>.<extension>`.

I guess the version you are looking for is this one:

```
for file in *
do
    mkdir -p ${file%.*}
    mv $file ${file%.*}/
done
```

Be sure to use the *ungreedy* variant wiht a single (!) `%` as you only want to remove the very last component from the filename.

Imagine a file named `first.part.second.part.txt` where you only want to strip `.txt` for example.

Given the following folder layout before (`find dir1`):

```
dir1/
dir1/two.txt
dir1/one.rtf
dir1/two.rtf
dir1/other.txt
dir1/other.rtf
dir1/one.txt
```

This will result in the following layout aftwards (`find dir1` again):

```
dir1
dir1/other
dir1/other/other.txt
dir1/one
dir1/one/one.rtf
dir1/one/one.txt
dir1/two
dir1/two/two.txt
dir1/two/two.rtf
```

If that is what you were looking for.